# Multiple images on root window with ImageMagick

Tags: xorg, imagemagick, stumpwm

I don't run a desktop environment, but instead use a bare window manager ([StumpWM](https://stumpwm.github.io/)). Thus, my usual method for setting a desktop background is to run `display -window root <image file>` from a WM startup script, which does what I want.

When using multiple monitors, the X root window stretches across both and includes dead space. Thus, running that command line causes the image to either be stretched or tiled across the entire window, which isn't useful. I can use `-geometry` to display an image on either monitor, but if I run that again (to view on both monitors) it overwrites the other. There doesn't seem to be any ability with `display` to display two images in one invocation.

How can I use `display` to display different images on both monitors? Alternatively, how else can I get the "desktop background image" effect without a desktop environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`montage`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/montage.php) to generate a single image that encompasses your whole display, and call `display -window root` on the resulting image.

Alternatively, you can use [`xloadimage`](http://sioseis.ucsd.edu/xloadimage.html) which is happy to tile multiple images. It doesn't know about separate monitors, so if your images aren't full-screen or if you have different-size monitors, you may need to use `-at` or `-geometry` to adjust the image positions manually.

```
xloadimage -onroot -at 1680,0 image1.jpg -at 0,0 image2.png
```

Comment: `xloadimage` works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up using:

```
DIR=$HOME/Pictures/Desktop
IMG1="$(ls $DIR/*jpg | shuf | head -1)"
IMG2="$(ls $DIR/*jpg | shuf | head -1)"
montage  -background "#000000" -geometry 1920x1080 $IMG1 $IMG2 jpg:- | display  -foreground "#000000" -backdrop  -window root jpg:-
```

Displays 2 random images on the root window, luckily my monitors are running at the same resolution.

Answer (score 0):

If the X-Server supports xrandr - I found using [xwallpaper](https://github.com/stoeckmann/xwallpaper) easier and straight forward. The following is a part from my Xsetup:

```bsh
# Display different wallpapers for each monitor
cmd='xwallpaper '
if xrandr --listactivemonitors
then
    # xrandr is available: get output names from xrandr
    for output in $(xrandr --listactivemonitors | cut -d ' ' -f6 )
    do
       # set different image for each monitor
       img=$(ls /usr/share/backgrounds/active/*.jpg | shuf | head -1 )
       cmd="$cmd --output $output --stretch $img "
    done
else
    # fallback: xrandr not available
    img=$(ls /usr/share/backgrounds/active/*.jpg | shuf | head -1 )
    cmd="$cmd --no-randr --stretch $img "
fi
$cmd
```

Comment: Nice solution, except shouldn't the head -1 come before the shuf in the pipeline?  Otherwise, won't a random line be stripped, rather than the "total=" line which I presume you're trying to remove?

Comment: You dont get a total line for ls. What that line is doing is to get a random image from the list of files.