# Randomly Cycle Different Wallpapers On Each Monitor

Tags: gnome3, multi-monitor, wallpaper

So I've got a program called "Display Fusion" installed on my Windows drive, and I love it for literally only one feature:

I can set it up to that each of my 3 monitors randomly changes the wallpaper every X minutes. I can point it at a folder I have of 500+ wallpapers, and each monitor will individually randomly pick one (so they hardly ever have the same wallpaper on each two screens).

---

I'm running Debian Jessie, with Gnome Shell 3.14.4, and so far I've tried the follow apps, and had the follow issues:

Nitrogen: Doesn't work at all. Can't set "Have File Manager handle Desktop" to "OFF" since Gnome Tweak Tool doesn't list that option anywhere.

Syncwall: Doesn't actually have any way to set different wallpapers for each monitor, but has the random cycling feature done perfectly.

---

Is there any other potential software I'm missing that can do what I'm trying to do?

Am I missing something obviously with the software I've already tried?

---

### Update 1:

Tried out the second code-block in Gilles' answer:

```
#!/bin/sh
wallpaper_directory= MY WALLPAPER FOLDER
interval=300 # in seconds
IFS='
'; set -ef
while true; do
  set $(find "$wallpaper_directory" -type f | shuf -r -n 3)
  xloadimage -onroot -at 0,0 "$1" -at 1920,0 "$2" -at 3840,0 "$3"
  sleep "$interval"
done
```

added it to `/etc/init.d/`

and ran `chmod 755 wallpaper_script.sh`

and `update-rc.d wallpaper_script.sh defaults`

So now, I've got my Tweak Tools settings set to the following:

[image: Gnome3 Tweak-Tools Desktop settings]

And my background on all 3 monitors is now a solid blue.

*BUT*, when I reboot (ans presumably after the Gnome Shell stops running) I can see 3 of my wallpapers flash right before the reboot happens.

So the script appears to be working, but Gnome is conflicting, and after digging around in gsettings and dconf-editor I still cant seem to find a setting that does what Tweak-Tools did back in Gnome2.

Comment: @drewbenn I've heard. But I'm too much of a Gnome-lover.

Answer (score 1):

If Gnome doesn't have anything built in, you can write a script to do it. The following loads random wallpapers from `~/wallpapers` on three monitors, assumed to be arranged left-to-right with each monitor being 1680 pixels wide. It uses [xloadimage](http://sioseis.ucsd.edu/xloadimage.html) (see [Multiple images on root window with ImageMagick](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269586/multiple-images-on-root-window-with-imagemagick/269588#269588)). Adjust the monitor sizes and the wallpaper locations as suitable. If you want the wallpapers to be distinct, remove the `-r` option to `shuf`. For more monitors, increase the parameter of `shuf -n`.

```
#!/bin/sh
IFS='
'; set -f
set $(find ~/wallpapers -type f | shuf -r -n 3)
xloadimage -onroot -at 0,0 "$1" -at 1680,0 "$2" -at 3360,0 "$3"
```

To change the wallpaper every N minutes, add the following script to your session startup applications.

```
#!/bin/sh
wallpaper_directory=~/wallpapers
interval=300 # in seconds
IFS='
'; set -ef
while true; do
  set $(find "$wallpaper_directory" -type f | shuf -r -n 3)
  xloadimage -onroot -at 0,0 "$1" -at 1680,0 "$2" -at 3360,0 "$3"
  sleep "$interval"
done
```

Here's a more complex script that calls [`xrandr`](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/xrandr.1.html) to get the monitor sizes and positions. This variant assumes that the wallpapers are in a subdirectory named after the monitor sizes, e.g. `~/wallpapers/1680x1050`.

```
#!/bin/sh
wallpaper_directory=~/wallpapers
interval=300 # in seconds

random_wallpaper () {
  find ~/wallpapers/$1 -type f | shuf -n 1
}
command="xloadimage -onroot"
i=1
for m in $(xrandr | sed -n 's/^.* connected.*[^0-9]\([0-9]*x[0-9]*\)+\([0-9]*\)+\([0-9]*\).*$/\1,\2,\3/p'); do
  size="${m%%,*}" position="${m#*,}"
  command="$command -at $position \"\$(random_wallpaper $size)\""
  i=$((i+1))
done

if ! eval "$command"; then
  echo >&2 "Unable to load initial wallpapers, aborting."
  exit 2
fi
while sleep "$interval"; do
  eval "$command"
done
```

(Warning: all code in this answer is untested.)

Alternatively, there may be a way to get Nitrogen to work by setting the the right value with `gsettings` (mimicking what the Tweak Tool did in Gnome 2), but I don't know what key needs to be changed.

Comment: So for 3 monitors @ 1920 wide each, I would just change this line `xloadimage -onroot -at 0,0 "$1" -at 1680,0 "$2"` to `xloadimage -onroot -at 0,0 "$1" -at 1920,0 "$2" -at 3840,0 "$3"`?

Comment: @WorseDoughnut Yes, and change `shuf -n 2` to `shuf -n 3`. I've also added a script that detects the monitor positions and sizes automatically (again, untested).

Comment: Awesome, I'll test this out when I get home. I'm actually glad there's a scripting solution to this, a much easier than trying to find software for my specific needs (hence why I'm using Debian in the first place).

Comment: Tried your second code-block / script out, please see my edit to the main question.